# How to Create Site using Sharepoint web services?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am tring to create site on sharepoint programatically using Sharepoint Web Services.(C#).

I tried Admin.asmx service (CreateSite method).

But it's showing error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll".

I tried with all possible parameters.
Curremtly referring Below Links:

1. http://www.oliebol.org/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/administration.admin.createsite.aspx

My Code:

```
Admin admService             = new Admin();
admService.Credentials       = new NetworkCredential(username,password,domain);
admService.Url               = "http://mychserver/_vti_adm/admin.asmx";
admService.PreAuthenticate   = true;
try
{
  String SitePath   = "http://myserver/SiteDirectory/SharepointSampleSite";
  admService.CreateSite(SitePath,"First Site", "Sample Site", 1033, "STS#0",
                       "Domain\\username",username,userid, "", "");
}
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Message:\n" + ex.Message + "\nDetail:\n" +ex.Detail.InnerText +
                 "\nStackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Thanx,

Comment: trying posting the full exception...with the inner exception...

Answer (score 1):

Is the account calling the service part of the Farm Admin group?

Using STS#0 as a param, thats a "Team Site".  Are the relevant features deployed/activated for the that Site Collection?

Are you able to call other web service methods successfully?

Comment: yes i am working with admin account and other web services are successfully working like DWS,List e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing STS#0 to STS#1.  STS#1 is a blank site.  If that works then you know the problem is with the site template.

Check the values for the parameters "OwnerLogin", "OwnerName", and "OwnerEmail".  Mine are of the format: domain\\username, username, username@domain.  Perhaps the email address is invalid (you are passing "userid" which I assume is not a valid email address?)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this as well, I think that it is related to the userid value.  Make sure that it is an email associated with the domain user you are using.  If the domain user does not have an email, leave the parameter blank.